# How to Maintain the State of CollectionView over different Segments (Tab)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm having a collection View flow layout added as a subview inside segmented control. The Segment is Categorised into `All, New, Used`.
My problem is how can I maintain the state of the collection view over different Segments. 
I'm Making API Calls for Loading the Data on `All, New, Used` segments 
Also Each time when I switch the Tab I'm calling `[collectionView reloadData]` Which reloads the collection view but not exactly the position where I left earlier in that particular segment
 
For example in `All` Segment I have Scrolled 10 - 15 items then i'm switching to `New` Segment and scrolling 3 Items and Now if I again Switch the Tab to `All` Segment then the Position of `All` Segment also goes to 3rd position

How can this be resolved. Thank you for reading patiently. Any Help would help me a lot.

Here is the sample code which I use for switching the Segment

```
-(IBAction)changeSeg:(id)sender{
    [collectionView reloadData];

    if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:false];
        typeFlag = 0;
        if ([inventoryDetails count] == 0 && totalInventoryCountForAll != 0) {
            [self loadMore];
        } else if (totalInventoryCountForAll == 0) {
            [self setNoCarVisibility: true];
        }
    }
    else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        typeFlag = 1;
        if ([newInventory count] == 0 && totalInventoryCountForNew != 0) {
            [self loadMore];
        } else if (totalInventoryCountForNew == 0) {
            [self setNoCarVisibility: true];
        }
    }
    else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
        typeFlag = 2;
        if([usedInventory count] == 0 && totalInventoryCountForUsed != 0){
            [self loadMore];
        } else if (totalInventoryCountForUsed == 0) {
            [self setNoCarVisibility: true];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Finally I got the Quick Solution as Follows:

1). I have created three Collection View for All, New, Used

2). Created the required Outlet Connection, Data Source and delegates for All three collection Views

3). The trick is to hide and show the collection view for currently selected segment.

4). But I face a minor issue here. The first Collection View (All Tab in my case) needs to be the last item on Interface builder, then only it will be shown when loading the collection view initially.

5). Whenever I switch the Tabs, I hide other two collection views and show the currently selected Tab's Collection view.

This may not be the correct solution. But for time being I did this.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can save the indexpath of currently visisble cell when you you switch tab scrolltoIndepath after reloadData.
Hope it helps....

**Edit**
Current indexpath each for 3 tabs separately. So there wont be one variable instead there will be 3 variables of indexpath individual to each tab, once tab switched manage the values in respective var and then relaod in same way.

For example currentAllIndexpath, currentNewIndexpath etc.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I have tried this too. But the Problem is I have made API Call  on willDisplayCell when the indexPath is reaching 10th position. So when I scroll to the Position programatically it automatically shows loading indicator which must be avoided. Also the willDisplayCell will set the current indexPath as a last scrolled position which cannot be made unique for All, new, Used segments

Comment: Tried the solution which you suggested in the edit. But unfortunately there is another  problem with willDisplayCell. when I switch the Tab, the first thing I'm doing is scrolling to the last selected position but actually the willDisplayCell is updating the current indexPath variable as a last scrolled position(even there is three separatevariables). So when I try to Scroll the indexPath before loading the cell, (the app crashes sometimes) it's not working or not scrolling to exactly where I left.